# Convert Unix Timestamp to Carbon Object

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have unix timestamp in table, wants to show to user using Carbon. How can I achieve ?

e.g.

```
1487663764.99256
```

To

```
2017-02-24 23:23:14.654621
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Did you check the carbon docs? I think this is what youre looking for:

```
Carbon::createFromTimestamp(-1)->toDateTimeString();
```

Checkout http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Comment: I sometimes forget the method name myself sometimes so when i google search "Carbon from unix timestap" and come across this post, im like heck yeah thumbs up for this guy and i get "you cant vote for your own post" lol :D

Comment: @surgiie LOL that moment when you realise

Comment: Actually Carbon::parse() does the same

Comment: LOL. Thanks for this answer. I may have came across this answer several times.. :-D

Comment: @miken32 aha you are right I just confirmed.

Answer (score 33):

There are several ways to create Carbon instances described in [the Carbon documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation), which is linked at the bottom of the project's README. The relevant section is this:

> The final two create functions are for working with unix timestamps. The first will create a Carbon instance equal to the given timestamp and will set the timezone as well or default it to the current timezone. The second, createFromTimestampUTC(), is different in that the timezone will remain UTC (GMT). The second acts the same as Carbon::createFromFormat('@'.$timestamp) but I have just made it a little more explicit. Negative timestamps are also allowed.

So you can just do:

```
$carbon = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($dbResult['SomeTimestampColumn']);
```

Comment: SO is better than docs. An idea could be to convert docs to SO format :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really love your fluid method calls and get frustrated by the extra line or ugly pair of brackets necessary when using the constructor you'll enjoy the parse method:

```
Carbon::parse(1487663764);
Carbon::parse('first day of next month');
```