# Carbon create from timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I am trying to convert some dates

```
<p>{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->diffForHumans()  }}</p>
```

This works fine as the date is in the format **2017-05-01 10:52:51**

However I also have the dates stored as unix timestamps.

How can I covert these to a date?

I already tried

```
{{  Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($post->created_at)->toDateTimeString()  }}
```

**Error - A non well formed numeric value encountered**

The dump is

```
 <pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr">
<small>int</small> 
<font color="#4e9a06">1493637826</font>
    </pre>
```

Comment: This is what I already tried Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($post->created_at)->toDateTimeString()  }}

Comment: No joy with that?

Comment: Hi Robbie, no this is how I thought it would work and checked out the documentation before. It only seems to work with 1 or -1 as the argument.

Comment: Can you share some example data from the `$post->created_at` value? (`var_export`)

Comment: Added, it's an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unix Timestamp to Carbon Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510921/convert-unix-timestamp-to-carbon-object)

Comment: I'll help you resolve this too because it doesn't seem to work for you...

Comment: Ok, I've tried this with Carbon and it works as expected. I haven't used Laravel, but from what I can tell your syntax looks fine. Sorry. Try direct PHP echo instead of `{{ }}`

Answer (score 8):

Your first attempt using `createFromTimestamp()` is correct, so there must be something wrong with your input. Here is a working example:

```
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1493637826)->toDateTimeString();
=> "2017-05-01 11:23:46"
```

The error you encountered suggests you're passing in a DateTime string, not a unix timestamp:

```
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp('2017-05-01 11:23:46')->toDateTimeString();
PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had  to use gmdate to convert the timestamp.

```
{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse(gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $post->date_posted))->diffForHumans()  }}
```

It is strange because it should work the way Robbie Averill suggested.